# UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uideviceorientation

I want to detect UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown. How can i do this???
Actually i want to perform some action when my iphone face is down on flat surface.
how is it possible??? plz help me to do this.

i have this code, but don't know where and how apply this code

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

 BOOL getOrientationUpdates = [[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
   NSLog(@"will receive orientation notifications: %@", getOrientationUpdates?@"YES":@"NO");

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                         name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

if there is any tutorial then please suggest me that

Thanks in Advance and most welcome to your precious help and suggestions.

Comment: When you say face down, do you mean face down on an object i.e table. or just face down in mid air?

Comment: It is face down on any object like table..

Comment: in that case use the proximerty censor. Its a light sensor that detects when the phone is put to your ear. see the last few slides of: http://learningiphoneprogramming.com/pdf/The_Sensors_in_your_iPhone.pdf

Comment: thanx gemini, but where i put this coding UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
BOOL state = device.proximityState;        in viewDidload???

Comment: yes It should work in your view did load fine. once you have initalised the device variable as you have above.you can then call write the [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
selector: @selector(proximityChanged:)
name: @"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification"
object: device]; you need to add a method called proximityChanged that will be called by the notification when the phone is put down.

Comment: is it working in simulator and ipod?? or only in iphone and ipad

Comment: It will oonly work on the device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by detecting the ProximityState of iPhone. Using the `[UIDevice currentDevice]` singleton, setting the `proximityMonitoringEnabled` to `YES`. you can access the proximity information through the proximityState property.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice]proximityState];
```

iPhone has a sensor turns off the screen when you put it on your ear during a call, AFAIK that is an infrared sensor. and you can access it.

EDIT:
You can also accomplish it using the below code. `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
The device is held parallel to the ground with the screen facing downwards.` (regardless if it touched any object) if you want to know if the iPhone touched an object, detect the proximity state of device.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(detectOrientation) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];


    -(void)detectOrientation;{

            switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
                case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
                {
                    NSLog(@"portrait");
                }
                    break;
                case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                {
                    NSLog(@"portraitUpSideDown");
                }
                    break;
                case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                {
                    NSLog(@"landscapeLeft");
                }
                    break;
                case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                {
                    NSLog(@"landscapeRight");
                }
                break;
               case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
               {
                    NSLog(@"facedown!!");
                }
                 break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    } 

}
```

EDIT: to answer the question in comment. add this line in your viewDidLoad

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleProximityChangeNotification:) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

then write a method

```
-(void)handleProximityChangeNotification{
     if([[UIDevice currentDevice]proximityState]){
        NSLog(@"...");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i got it.. but where i put the code in viewController to get proximityState

Comment: do you want to know if the device touched an object?

Comment: @Rox I edited the answer, the code is not tested. but you can give it a try.

Comment: one more thing, is it working in simulator and ipod?? or only in iphone and ipad???

Comment: @Rox can you touch the simulator and put it on your table? :)

Comment: @Rox i am not sure if iPod and iPad has proximity sensor, you can just google it if you go with this approach.

Comment: yea, ipod don't have proximity sensor... ok, janusfidel can u tell i have many viewController classes may be more than 10, then in this situation i have to mention this code in every class's viewDidLoad method or there is any way in appdelegate  which detect it whatever in  any class i m.

Comment: Awesome breakdown. Awesome code example. Great answer is great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the z value from accelerometer sensor (-1 <= z <= 1). If your device is facing down, the z value will be in 0 < z <=1 (0 when it's facing parallel to the ground, 1 when it's facing perpendicular to the ground). To get this data you can use `CMMotionManager`

```
 #import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h> 

 CMMotionManager *cm=[[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
 cm.deviceMotionUpdateInterval=0.2f;
 [cm startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                            withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *data, NSError *error) {
                              if(data.gravity.z>=0.3f)// 

                              {
                                 //DO something
                              }

  }];
```

Don't forget to add `CoreMotion` framework to your project.